# Можно ли на своем компьютере развернуть на локальном сервере чужой Django проект?

Tags: django

Есть django проект, с которым я хочу работать на двух разных компьютерах и размещать этот проект на локальном сервере каждого ПК. Так вот, можно ли так сделать, чтобы вводя localhost 8000, проект открывался на другом компьютере (не на котором он был изначально создан) ? Если да, то как (ну, или как это загуглить можно) ? Заранее безумно благодарен. P.S Виртуальное окружение имеется и были загружены одинаковые библиотеки одинаковых версий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В консоли, в директории проекта (там где находится файл `manage.py`) нужно выполнить следующее:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

либо для Windows-операционных систем:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```